# Spacex NASA GOES-U 2024 contract to use Falcon Heavy?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy

https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-awards-launch-services-contract-for-goes-u-mission
Why would they use Falcon-Heavy instead of Falcon-9 FT for the GOES-U 2024 satellite launch?

Falcon-9 FT has the following specifications to geosynchronous orbit.
5,500kg to GTO reusable, 8,300kg to GTO expendable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-lift_launch_vehicle

And according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOES-U the launch mass of the GOES-U is only 2,800kg, which is well within the range of an ordinary reusable FALCON-9 FT, so why would the contract specify using FALCON-HEAVY?  Also, could this change to Starship?  Starship should have launched several flights by 2024 ...

Comment: I don't know, but it is possible that they will put like it to be put into a higher energy orbit than the minimal GTO used for those numbers in order to save orbit-raising time and/or satellite propellant cf [What is meant by "a high-energy geostationary orbit"? (SpaceX Arabsat 6A)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34968/12102) and [What will be "unique" about upcoming SES-9 GTO transfer profile by SpaceX?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14191/12102) and [How did SES-9 reach geostationary orbit from inclined transfer orbit (from F9 2nd stage)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14198/12102)

Comment: [it looks like](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/goes-r.htm) has an [LEROS 1c Apogee Engine](https://www.nammo.com/product/leros-1c/) so the time saving would not be as much as it would be if it were an all-electric propulsion satellite, but the propellant savings would be much larger than if it were electric. That propellant might be better used for station keeping and station-changing. However I don't think the GOES-U (to become [GOES-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOES-U) once deployed and commissioned) is planned to be doing a heck of a lot of that.

Comment: Wiki info is incorrect. It confuses dry mass with launch mass. If you check GOES-16 and -17, they have dry mass ~2800 and launch mass over 5000 kg. The last GOES satellites have been launched by Atlas V rocket in 541 configuration - the second most powerful Atlas with 4 strap-on solid busters. (Another example that Wikipedia can be a starting point, but should be checked)